# The different generators of canonical transformations

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, vector-fields, phase-space, poisson-brackets

Consider the phase space of a one degree of freedom mechanical system. We can pass from one phase space coordinates to another phase space coordinates via a canonical transformation. I want to focus on 1-parameter canonical transformations,

$$(q_{0},p_{0})\rightarrow(q_{\lambda},p_{\lambda})$$

where $\lambda\in[0,\infty)$ parametrize the transformation.

By the standard theory, there exist a function $F=F_{1}(q_{0},q_{\lambda};\lambda)$ such that

$$p_{0}\frac{dq_{0}}{dt}-H=p_{\lambda}\frac{dq_{\lambda}}{dt}-K+\frac{dF_{1}}{dt}.$$

$F$ is called the generator of the transformation, and the following equation follows

$$p_{0}    =\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial q_{0}},\qquad p_{\lambda}=-\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial q_{\lambda}},\qquad K=H+\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial t}.$$

Now, also by standard theory, there exists a function  $W=W(q,p;\lambda)$ such that the transformation can be obtained via the Poisson brackets using the equations

$$\frac{dq}{d\lambda}    =\left\{ q,W\right\}, $$

$$\frac{dp}{d\lambda}    =\left\{ p,W\right\}.$$

$W$ is again sometimes called the generator of the transformation.

What is the relation between $F$ and $W $?

Comment: For the record, I found the solution to the question in an old paper https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-8914(73)90090-6 It is a generalization of the relation between Hamilton's principal functions and the Hamiltonian in the Hamilton-Jacobi theory.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question.

1. Given a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$ let there be given a time-dependent generator $G\in C^{\infty}(M\times \mathbb{R})$ of a [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_G$. Then we have a 1-parameter [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism) [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)), here written in local canonical/Darboux coordinates
   $$\begin{align}
   \frac{dz^I_{\lambda}}{d\lambda}~=~& \{G(z_{\lambda},t),z^I_{\lambda}\}, \cr
   z^I_{\lambda} ~=~&e^{\lambda\{G(z_0,t),\cdot\}} z^I_0\cr ~=~&z^I_0 +\lambda\{G(z_0,t),z^I_0\} 
   +{\cal O}(\lambda^2), \cr 
   I~\in~&\{1,\ldots, 2n\},\cr 
   (z^1_{\lambda},\ldots, z^{2n}_{\lambda})~=~&(q^1_{\lambda},\ldots, q^{n}_{\lambda},p_{1\lambda},\ldots, p_{n\lambda}).
    \end{align}\tag{1}$$
2. Note that only type-2 and type-3 (but never type-1 and type-4) [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation)s are guaranteed to exist in a neighborhood of the identity CT. Let us therefore pick a 1-parameter type-2 generating function
   $$\begin{align}
   F_2(q_0,p_{\lambda},t,\lambda)~=~&q^i_0 p_{i\lambda} +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!} F_{2m}(q_0,p_{\lambda},t),\cr
    q^i_{\lambda} 
   ~=~ \frac{\partial F_2(q_0,p_{\lambda},t,\lambda)}{\partial p_{i\lambda} }
   ~=~& q^i_0  +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \frac{\partial F_{2m}(q_0,p_{\lambda},t)}{\partial p_{i\lambda} } ,\cr
   p_{i0} 
   ~=~ \frac{\partial F_2(q_0,p_{\lambda},t,\lambda)}{\partial q^i_0}~=~& p_{i\lambda}  +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \frac{\partial F_{2m}(q_0,p_{\lambda},t)}{\partial q^i_0 } ,\cr
   i~\in~&\{1,\ldots, n\}.
   \end{align}\tag{2}$$
   (There are similar expressions for a type-3 CT.)
   As one can imagine the relationship between $F_2$ and $G$ is quite intricate in general, cf. OP's question.
3. Let us for simplicity consider an infinitesimal CT, i.e. let $\lambda$ be infinitesimally small. Then one may show that the relationship is
   $$\begin{align} F_2(q_0,p_{\lambda},t,\lambda)
   ~=~&q^i_0p_{i\lambda}- \lambda G(q_0,p_{\lambda},t)
   +{\cal O}(\lambda^2)\cr
   ~=~&q^i_0p_{i\lambda}- \lambda G(q_0,p_0,t)
   +{\cal O}(\lambda^2),
   \end{align}\tag{3} $$
   cf. Ref. 1.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* eq. (9.62).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. I'm aware of Goldstein's results, I'm looking for the general result for finite transformations. 2. Btw, why only  F2 and F3 are guaranteed to exist for infinitesimal transformations?

Comment: 2. It is fairly straightforward to show that one cannot write the identity CT as type-1 or type-4.